# how to call super in closure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I want to chain a func to super impl, something like the following

```
class BaseClass {
  func myFunc() {
    // do something
  }
}

class MyClass: BaseClass {
  override func myFunc() {
    self.myOtherFunc(completionHandler: {
      super.myFunc() // error: 'super' members cannot be referenced in a non-class type
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

The compilation error actually tells me the reason clearly: closure is not a class type and it is not allowed.  Looking for any suggestion How do I invoke the method defined in super class?

Comment: I feel that this is a bug, because if `self` is available, then `super` should be available, because `super` is just `self` called with a different method lookup scheme.

Comment: But the method lookup scheme is "start looking below the class that this method belongs to", and that information isn't there in the closure.

Comment: This really feels like one of those "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should". But it has fascinating implications. What happens if you defer the super call to a class constructor? The mind boggles

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:** As of Swift 1.2 b3, this behavior is fixed—the original code works as intended. Yay, progress!

```
class BaseClass {
    func myFunc() {
        println("BaseClass.myFunc()")
    }
}

class MyClass: BaseClass {
    func myOtherFunc(c: () -> ()) {
        c()
    }

    override func myFunc() {
        println("MyClass.myFunc()")
        self.myOtherFunc {
            super.myFunc()
        }
    }
}

MyClass().myFunc()
// MyClass.myFunc()
// BaseClass.myFunc()
```

---

Ideally you could just write:

```
class MyClass: BaseClass {
  override func myFunc() {
    let superFunc = super.myFunc
    self.myOtherFunc(completionHandler: {
      superFunc()
    })
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work, it just calls `self.myFunc()`. I [tweeted about this](https://twitter.com/nnnnnnnn/status/534508131187822592) the other day and got a [response from one of the Swift developers](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/534508771733557248) that it's a known bug. The only workaround is to use another method to shuttle the call to super:

```
class MyClass: BaseClass {
  override func myFunc() {
    self.myOtherFunc(completionHandler: {
      self.callSuperMyFunc()
    })
  }

  func callSuperMyFunc() {
    super.myFunc()
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to give Nat and rintaro both correct answer. Since I can only choose one, I like the naming that "kinda" suggest temporarily workaround: for now, I name it: superMyFunc (for super.myFunc). rintaro does has his point for the naming though. Definitely, good to know this is a temporary bug.

Answer (score 6):

This answer might not answering your question..

Surprisingly, the following code causes infinite recursive call. Maybe a bug?

```
class MyClass: BaseClass {
    override func myFunc() {
        let superMyFunc = super.myFunc
        self.myOtherFunc(completionHandler: {
            superMyFunc() // this actually calls MyClass.myFunc
            return
        })
    }
}

// ALSO
class MyClass: BaseClass {
    override func myFunc() {
        let superMyFunc = BaseClass.myFunc(self as BaseClass)
        self.myOtherFunc(completionHandler: {
            superMyFunc() // this actually calls MyClass.myFunc
            return
        })
    }
}
```

The only workaround I found out is defining another method:

```
class MyClass: BaseClass {
    override func myFunc() {
        self.myOtherFunc(completionHandler: {
            self.callSuperMyFunc()
            return
        })
    }
    func callSuperMyFunc() {
        super.myFunc()
    }
}
```

But, I think, you should use another method name:

```
class MyClass: BaseClass {
    func myFuncAsync() {
        self.myOtherFunc(completionHandler: {
            self.myFunc()
            return
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Creating a helper method to call super is really the way to go here, as there's still no way to weakly capture super (needed for escaping closures).

Answer (score 0):

I use next approach:

```
let parentFunction = super.function
functionWithClosure {
    parentFunction()
}
```

Comment: That's working for me. With Swift 5.3, I was still getting this issue. One small downside is that because `parentFunction` is now a closure, you have to get rid of the argument labels.

Comment: Doesn't this code cause `super.function` to execute when assigning to `parentFunction` variable?

Comment: No, because the function itself is assigned to the `parentFunction` (like a reference to a function).

Comment: @Adam yes i faced it: causes `super.function` to execute when assigning to parentFunction